# Implications of increasing MAX_NUM_COOKIES

Tags: magento2, cookie

Magento 2 allows 50 cookies per domain.
This limit is enforced by `Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager::MAX_NUM_COOKIES`.
What are the implications of increasing that value?
I've read [how to change constants of class in Magento\Framwork?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/187003/146) and the accepted answer states

> ... incompatibility with several more or less outdated browsers, depending on much you increase it.
>   Especially IE 11 and lower have the 50 Cookie per domain limit and still a relevant market share.

But I don't exactly understand what would happen on IE11 and lower.
Does this mean that the website will not function properly or the cookies that come in from 50 upwards don't get set? Or anything else?
If I don't care how the website behaves on IE, is it safe to increase this number?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714724/what-happens-if-i-exceed-the-limit-of-maximum-cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser will just automaticlly discard older cookies.

Ref:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/941495/internet-explorer-increases-the-per-domain-cookie-limit-from-20-to-50

Comment: this means that at one point it could discard the session cookie? If yes, will that be ever set again?

Comment: Hmm I think they will be removed by older go to limit and stop again.