# Overriding Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Is there anyway to override `Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager::MAX_NUM_COOKIES` ?

I tried everything, using preference in module `di.xml` or `app/etc/di.xml`
or using aliases in application.config.php and `di.config.php` but no luck.
I need to increase the value of `MAX_NUM_COOKIES`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change constants of class in Magento\Framwork?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187003/how-to-change-constants-of-class-in-magento-framwork)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy this file

> vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php

Here

> lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php

And then you can change this variable's value there.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: You just saved my day, sir. thx!